# Video plays very fast some times in avplayer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In Avplayer, we apply the rate for video slow motion and negative frame also. if video ends and apply the rate to avplayer the video plays very fastly instead of given rate. i was struggled more than 2 days. Thanks

Comment: So… what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `[avPlayer setRate:0.3]` and `[avPlayer play]` at the same time, so the second call override the first call, which sets the rate to be 0 (normal). 
The method setRate: already set the rate for the player and play the video already

Comment: Hi, if we call [avPlayer play] which sets rate to be 1 not 0. can u check again please.